# Android View add child

Tags: java, android, view, textview

I have the following View and TextView, How can I add the TextView to the View as it's child ?

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context);

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Hello My Friends");

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `View` use `ViewGroup` to extend your `CustomView` class..

A [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) is a special view that can contain other views (called children.) The view group is the base class for layouts and views containers.

Something Like,

```
public class MyView extends ViewGroup
```

Now, you can use method called

```
public void addView (View child)
```

Adds a child view. If no layout parameters are already set on the child, the default parameters for this ViewGroup are set on the child.

Answer (score 5):

You can't add child to view. Only to ViewGroup